# Argument checking in R

Tags: r, parameter-passing

In R, I wrote a function like:

```
fun <- function(A, B, C, D) {}
```

So, at the beginning of this function, I must do argument checking:

- Is some required arguments missing
- Is all arguments following the rules: **class(data type)** or **A must be in range [1:3]**

But about these arguments, some are required, some are not, and the **class(data type)** of each argument must be what I want, for example: **numeric**, **logical**, and so on...

To accomplish this, I did things like：

```
if(A Follow_the_rule){}
if(B Follow_the_rule){}
if(C Follow_the_rule){}
...
```

About the code above, so much **if** statements are required which I think isn't the best way of argument checking.

So **Is there a better way to check arguments in R?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if (missing(A)) stop ("A is missing")`

Comment: Browse the source code of some packages (easiest on Github) and look how experienced package authors do this.

Comment: **If** condition certainly can do this, but the thing is that if I got lots of arguments, I have to write lots of **If() stop()** statements, which I think is not the best way to do argument checking. Thanks for help.

Comment: Also check the [checkmate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkmate/index.html) package from CRAN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at `?stopifnot` which does exactly what you want. It checks for the condition within and stops if the condition is not given. The same as in `if`, you can concatenate conditions with `&&` or `||` and `&` amd `|`. See information with e.g. `?"&"`. Further helpful may also be `all` or `any` to check if all elements of a given vector fulfill the condition or any, respectively. Some examples:

```
foo <- function(A, B, C){
  stopifnot(!missing(C), !missing(B), !missing(A)) ##A, B, C not missing, then continue
  stopifnot(class(B)=="matrix") ## B is a matrix, then continue
  stopifnot(class(B)==class(C), all(B > C)) ## class B is class C and all elements of B are greater than C
  stopifnot((length(A)>1 && !any(is.na(A))) || all(A==0)) ## (A has more than 1 element and no element is NA) or all elements of A are 0.
  stopifnot(all(A > 2), all(A < 10)) ## all elements of A are between 2 and 10, else stop.

  #... further code
}
```

The conditions above may not fit together in this combination, but I think there are enough examples for you to adapt to your problem. Of course you could write all in one `stopifnot`, but it is more useful to group the conditions if there are many, because the condition which stops the function is printed as error code. So the more `stopifnot` you have, the more precise is the error information you get.

Comment: But still, do I have to check all these parameters with lots of **if(condition) stop("Error Message")** or **stopifnot** (I think the former one is better since you can write why it goes wrong), Or I can just  leave it to R.

Comment: R will probably throw an error itself if a needed variable is missing at some point in the function, but it is good habit to check and possibly convert the variables at the beginning of the function call. Else you would do some (then useless) calculations just to see that something else is breaking the code later on. You can of course group your variables and check each group like: ``L <- list(A, B, C)`` ``all(sapply(L, class) == "matrix")`` or ``any(is.na(unlist(L)))``.

Comment: `stopifnot` accepts `...` arguments, so all checks could be passed at the same time -- `stopifnot(!missing(A), class(B) == "matrix", ..)`

Comment: Appreciate your help. So I think that reporting which argument is wrong when calling a function is better, rather than reporting there's a problem within all the arguments. To accomplish that specific purpose,meaning I have to write **if() stop()** for every argument, don't you think so ?

Comment: I think that depends on 1: What kind of arguments you have and what kind of checks you want to apply (``L <- list(A, B, C, D, ...)``) will throw an error like: ``Object D is missing``. I gave another example in my previous comment if you want to check the same class of more objects at once. ``if .. stop ..`` has the advantage that you can write your own error messages where as ``stopifnot`` gives default error messages.